# trouble configuring a DNS to point a domain at the server’s IP in a vagrant virtual machine

Tags: django, nginx, dns, vagrant, gunicorn

Im trying the following guide: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Im trying to get my Django app working with nginx and gunicorn. 
The problem is that in the start of the guide his writing: "I’m also assuming you configured your DNS to point a domain at the server’s IP. In this text, I pretend your domain is..."
how would i configure that? especially since I'm working on a linux machine vm(vagrant).
until now I just used localhost/...

Comment: Need more info.  Is your VM hosted or is it on a machine that you own?  If it's hosted, usually the VPS/VM provider will give you some interface to create a DNS record pointing your domain name to the IP of your server.  If you're hosting it on your own local server, you'll need to use some DNS hosting service to point the domain name to your machine's IP.  This might be better suited on ServerFault.

Comment: Im running everything locally. I have a os x, on that I am using vagrant to run precise64 linux. In that VM I have all my django apps and virtualenv. I don't exactly understand why do the author requires setting up a DNS for this guide, but It's the only guide I found.

Comment: For now, you could just try your IP in place of the domain name.  I forget if nginx hates IP addresses or not.  If that doesn't work, you could just set up the hostname locally in your `/etc/hosts`, to point to the IP, then use that hostname in your nginx config.